# storing arrays in closure

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

Is this the best way to update array using closure. I saw something similar to this on another site.  I was wondering about the global variable `closure1` that is created.  Is there a way to do this without creating a global.

```
<script>  
    var closure1=Closure(0, 0);

    function Closure(num, i) {
        var num=num;
        var index=i;
        var anArray = [];
        return function(num,index) {
          anArray[index]=(num);
          out.innerHTML=anArray;
        }
    } 
 </script>

<div id="d1" onclick=" closure1(2,0)">2 index 0</div>
<div id="d2" onclick=" closure1(5,3)">5 index 3</div>
<div id="d3" onclick=" closure1(4,1)">4 index 1</div>
<div id="d4" onclick=" closure1(9,7)">9 index 7</div>
<div id="out" >?</div>
```

Comment: What are the two parameters passed to Closure() for? Their values are saved in local variables that never get used by the returned anonymous function.

Comment: I left that stuff out because it did not pertain to the question.  Basically I am moving away from local arrays to closures.  The actual array values will be pushed to the function via another function, and not an onclick.

Comment: OK, but we can't answer your "Is this the best way..." question if you don't show something closer to your real code. Inline event attributes would need globals, but now you say you're not actually using those, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a way to call the closure that you have created to use it within the `onclick` attributes. The advantage of having `closure1` as a global variable is that the closure is created just once and you can re-use it throught the page by just calling `closure1(num, index)`. If however you don't like to have a variable named `closure1` in your global scope you could *clean up* in the following way.

**EDIT :** I had posted two suggested ways earlier. Thanks to @nnnnnn for pointing out that one of the ways would break the OP's code. I have removed the incorrect suggestion and left the correct suggestion as it is.

You could add closures as properties to the existing `Closure` function. For example, if you want to create a new closure `closure1` you should create it like this

Remove the line:

```
var closure1=Closure(0, 0);
```

add the following line *AFTER* the `Closure` function has been defined, like so:

```
Closure.closure1 = Closure(0, 0);
```

and replace your onclicks with

```
<div id="d1" onclick="Closure.closure1(2,0)">2 index 0</div>
```

The complete code would then look as follows:

```
<script>  
    function Closure(num, i) {
        var num=num;
        var index=i;
        var anArray = [];
        return function(num,index) {
          anArray[index]=(num);
          out.innerHTML=anArray;
        }
    } 

    Closure.closure1 = Closure(0, 0);
 </script>

<div id="d1" onclick="Closure.closure1(2,0)">2 index 0</div>
<div id="d2" onclick="Closure.closure1(5,3)">5 index 3</div>
<div id="d3" onclick="Closure.closure1(4,1)">4 index 1</div>
<div id="d4" onclick="Closure.closure1(9,7)">9 index 7</div>
<div id="out" >?</div>
```

This is the cleanest approach in my opinion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your option 1 is not an equivalent to the OP's code because each instance would have its own array instead of sharing the same array.

Comment: having trouble getting the code to work.  Where does "Closure.closure1 = Closure(0, 0);"  go?  I've tried it both inside, and outside of the function.

Comment: @user1740058 Updated my answer. You need to write the line _after_ the closure function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this. Wrap the script in a self executing function, if you dont want to create a global variable.

```
(function(){
      var closure1=Closure(0, 0);

      function Closure(num, i) {
        var num=num;
        var index=i;
        var anArray = [];
        return function(num,index) {
          anArray[index]=(num);
          out.innerHTML=anArray;
        }
      }
  }());
```

Comment: that did not work because now closure1 is local and cannot be called outside of the function

Comment: @user1740058 - True, but your question was about doing it without a global, which won't work with inline event attributes. You can't have it both ways.